# How do I fix an "Incompatible Type" error in my program?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, incompatibletypeerror

I am trying to make a make a account program for Java. I have most of it type out but I am having trouble with the date and printing.

I am trying to

- Print the accounts monthly interest.
- Print the accounts monthly interest rate.
- Withdraw $7,500 from the account.
- Print the accounts monthly interest again.
- Deposit $11,0000 in the account.
- Print the monthly Interest

**ERRORS**

- In my class in `DateCreated`.

  ```
  Incompatible type: Date cannot be converted to String
  ```
- In my main class, `getDateCreated` and `getAnnualInterest` both have cannot find symbol errors.

Here is my code for main

```
    package testaccount;

    public class TestAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account1 = new Account(5648, 27000, 3.9);
        account1.withdraw(7500);
        account1.deposit(11000); 
        System.out.println("Your current balance is" +account1.getBalance());
        System.out.println("Monthly interest is"+ account1.getAnnualInterestRate);
        System.out.println("The account was created on" + account1.getDateCreated);
    }

}
```

Here's the code for my class

```
    package testaccount;

    import java.util.Date;

    public class Account {

    private int id;
    private double balance;
    private double annualInterestRate;
    private Date dateCreated;

    Account() {
        id = 0;
        balance = 0.0;
        annualInterestRate = 0.0;
    }

    Account(int Nid, double NBalance) {
        id = Nid;
        balance = NBalance;
    }

    Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }

    double withdraw(double amount) {
        return balance -= amount;
    }

    double deposit(double amount) {
        return balance += amount;
    }

    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date newDateCreated){
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    double getannaulnterestRate(){
        return annualInterestRate/12;
    }

    public String getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean `System.out.println("Monthly interest is"+ account1.getAnnualInterestRate())`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return date in `String` format:

```
public String getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated.toString();
    }
```

It seems you are also not setting date when instantiating an account object. You need to use it like:

```
account.setDateCreated(new Date());
```

Or better pass `Date` in constructor itself. It seems you need to read about constructor, method and other basic constructs of a class.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting cannot find symbol errors is that you are trying to access them as fields when they are in fact methods:

```
System.out.println("Monthly interest is"+ account1.getAnnualInterestRate);
System.out.println("The account was created on" + account1.getDateCreated);
```

Should be:

```
System.out.println("Monthly interest is"+ account1.getAnnualInterestRate());
System.out.println("The account was created on" + account1.getDateCreated());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Main Class Code**

```
public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Date date= new Date();
         Account account1 = new Account(5648, 27000, date);
            account1.withdraw(7500);
            account1.deposit(11000); 
            System.out.println("Your current balance is" +account1.getBalance());
            System.out.println("Monthly interest is"+ account1.getAnnualInterestRate());
            System.out.println("The account was created on" + account1.getDateCreated());
            }
    }
```

**Account class Code**

```
import java.util.Date;


public class Account {

     private int id;
        private double balance;
        private double annualInterestRate;
        private Date dateCreated;

        Account() {
            id = 0;
            balance = 0.0;
            annualInterestRate = 0.0;
        }

        Account(int Nid, double NBalance) {
            id = Nid;
            balance = NBalance;
        }


        Account(double balance, double annualInterestRate, Date dateCreated ) {
            this.balance = balance;
            this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
            this.dateCreated=dateCreated;

        }

        Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate, Date dateCreated ) {
            this.id = id;
            this.balance = balance;
            this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
            this.dateCreated=dateCreated;

        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public double getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }

        public void setBalance(double balance) {
            this.balance = balance;
        }

        public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
            return annualInterestRate;
        }

        double withdraw(double amount) {
            return balance -= amount;
        }

        double deposit(double amount) {
            return balance += amount;
        }

        public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
            this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
        }
        public void setDateCreated(Date newDateCreated){
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }
        double getannaulnterestRate(){
        return annualInterestRate/12;
    }
        public Date getDateCreated() {
            return dateCreated;
        }


}
```